# Typescript - multidimensional array initialization

Tags: multidimensional-array, typescript

I'm playing with Typescript and I wonder, how to properly instantiate and declare multidimensional array. Here's my code:

```
class Something {
    private things: Thing[][];

    constructor() {
        things = [][]; ??? how instantiate object ???

        for(var i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.things[i] = new Thing[];   ??? how instantiate 1st level ???
            for(var j: number = 0; j< 10; j++) {
                this.things[i][j] = new Thing();   ??? how instantiate 2nd lvl item ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you give me any hint about selected places?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You only need `[]` to instantiate an array - this is true regardless of its type. The fact that the array is of an array type is immaterial.

The same thing applies at the first level in your loop. It is merely an array and `[]` is a new empty array - job done.

As for the second level, if `Thing` is a class then `new Thing()` will be just fine. Otherwise, depending on the type, you may need a factory function or other expression to create one.

```
class Something {
    private things: Thing[][];

    constructor() {
        this.things = [];

        for(var i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.things[i] = [];
            for(var j: number = 0; j< 10; j++) {
                this.things[i][j] = new Thing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't imagine, how typings are preserved here. Can you give me any examples, please?

Comment: There are 0 items in the array, so there's no value or object to type.

Comment: I guess, it should be `this.things = [];` in the constructor.

Answer (score 33):

Here is an example of initializing a `boolean[][]`:

```
const n = 8; // or some dynamic value
const palindrome: boolean[][] = new Array(n)
                                   .fill(false)
                                   .map(() => 
                                     new Array(n).fill(false)
                                   );
```

Comment: shorter `new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(false))`

Comment: @Tukkan it will not work as expected: try to modify `palindrome[0][0]` and see what happens... ;)

Comment: @NirAlfasi yup, I checked and it works :)

Comment: Nope! if you'll define `p = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(false))` and then modify `p[0][0] = true` you'll see that the whole column changes instead of a single cell!

Answer (score 22):

If you want to do it typed:

```
class Something {

  areas: Area[][];

  constructor() {
    this.areas = new Array<Array<Area>>();
    for (let y = 0; y <= 100; y++) {
      let row:Area[]  = new Array<Area>();      
      for (let x = 0; x <=100; x++){
        row.push(new Area(x, y));
      }
      this.areas.push(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not everyone is using AngularJs to write JS/TS code.

Comment: This is just standard TS code, right? What do you see as AngularJs specific?  I prefer this solution with types.  Thanks

Comment: @WhatWouldBeCool the answer was edited to remove AngularJs specific code

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following (which I find trivial, but its actually correct).
For anyone trying to find how to initialize a two-dimensional array in TypeScript (like myself).

Let's assume that you want to initialize a two-dimensional array, of any type. You can do the following

```
const myArray: any[][] = [];
```

And later, when you want to populate it, you can do the following:

```
myArray.push([<your value goes here>]);
```

A short example of the above can be the following:

```
const myArray: string[][] = []; 
myArray.push(["value1", "value2"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thing {};

const rowSize = 3;
const colSize = 3;

const arr: Thing[][] = new Array(rowSize).fill(
                         new Array(colSize).fill(new Thing())
                       );
```

Answer (score -3):

Beware of the use of push method, if you don't use indexes, it won't work!

```
var main2dArray: Things[][] = []

main2dArray.push(someTmp1dArray)
main2dArray.push(someOtherTmp1dArray)
```

**gives only a 1 line array**!

use

```
main2dArray[0] = someTmp1dArray
main2dArray[1] = someOtherTmp1dArray
```

**to get your 2d array working**!!!

Other beware! **foreach doesn't seem to work** with 2d arrays!