# typescript multidimensional array with different types

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, types, typescript, angular

I have an custom object declared (ThreadObj) and I want to create a THREADLISTS, holding multiple arrays of Threadlist. So

```
Threadlist:ThreadObj[]=[];
THREADLISTS:[ThreadObj[]][ThreadObj]=[][]; //how to type and init?
```

The first dim is of ThreadObj[] and the second is of ThreadObj.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - multidimensional array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144580/typescript-multidimensional-array-initialization)

Comment: I've seen that thread, which unfortunately does not explain the typing question

Comment: I believe it does—`ThreadObj[][]`. If that's not what you mean then can you provide an example of `THREADLISTS` use? Maybe we're misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example :

```
type ThreadObj = {foo:string}
type ThreadList = ThreadObj[]; 
type ThreadListList = ThreadList[];

const obj: ThreadObj = {
    foo: '123'
}
const singleDim: ThreadList = [
    obj
]
const multiDim: ThreadListList = [
    singleDim,
    singleDim
]
```

## More

All in one step:

```
const allInOneStep: {foo:string}[][] = [
    [
        {
            foo: 'hello'
        },
        {
            foo: 'is it me'
        }
    ],
    [ 
        {
            foo: 'you are looking for'
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't that just be:

```
let arr:ThreadObj[][] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-dimensional array in typescript, you can simply declare and define the variable as

```
let multiArr:(string|number)[][] = [["Ram","Shyam",1,2,3,"Hari"]];
```