# How to type a multidimensional array whose each array has different type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, types

For a multidimensional array whose every element has the same type, it's simple to declare: `string[][]`.

However if each array is different, then how should I do?

```cs
function create3DArray(arg): // <----???
{ firstArray: string[] = [] 
  secondArray: number[] = [] 
  thirdArray: CustomType[] = [] 
  return [firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray] 
}
```

I have looked at [typescript multidimensional array with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36588385/3416774) but I'm still not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a *tuple*. *Tuple* is an array with finite length, in your case, it is three:

```
function create2DArray(arg):[string[], number[], CustomType[]] {}
```

Comment: thanks. If I want to shorten it, i.e. `function create3DArray(arg): MArray {}`, should I use type or interface for it? It seems that interface is only usable for objects, right?

Comment: Yeah, just go simply with the type

Comment: why is interface only usable with objects but type can work with any, ugh, type?

Comment: you can, but it will still require a `type`: `type MyArrBase = [string[], number[], boolean[]]`
`interface MyArray extends MyArrBase  {}`

Comment: I mean, why doesn't interface support array at the start?

Comment: I think it is a design limitation.