# How to instantiate multidimensional array in typescript of fixed length?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am making an array of array (a grid) in typescript. I need this array to be 5x4. I am trying to understand how to instantiate it.
I know I can do like this for a one dimension array:

let myvar:string[]=new Array(3);

I tried that way but it didn't work when I am trying to push an element. It is saying that my array has 0 line.

```
export class grid {

    public mainGrid: string[][];

public constructor() {

        this.mainGrid = new Array<Array<string>(5)>(4);
    }

}
```

Or should I push a new Array(5) for times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - multidimensional array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144580/typescript-multidimensional-array-initialization)

Comment: So I can't initiate the 2 array in one sentence?

Comment: well, you could, but it wouldn't be pretty or extensible

Comment: So 1st I instantiate the this.mainGrid = new Array<Array<string>>(); then I loop and push new Array<string>()?

Comment: Javascript (and typescript) doesn't have multidimensional arrays.  Typically, arrays of arrays are used instead.  Indeed, you'd create a `string[][]`, and iterate once to create each inner array.

Comment: @recursive array of array is the same as a multi dimensional array. How are you distinguishing the two ? It's the same thing from a logic point of view. Btw nice profile :)

Comment: @Ced:  They are different.  For example.  An array of arrays can contain rows that are different lengths.

Answer (score -2):

In JS you could do something like:

```
let elem = 0;//
let arr1 = [elem,elem,elem,elem];
let arr2 = [elem,elem,elem,elem];
let arr3 = [elem,elem,elem,elem];
let arr4 = [elem,elem,elem,elem];
let arr5 = [elem,elem,elem,elem];
let grid = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5];
```

but you will have to control that the length is not surpassed...