# angular2 array of boolean

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

When declaring this :

```
public isCollapsedDet : boolean[][];
public isCollapsedCyc : boolean[] ;
```

I got the following error message :

```
/nestedForm/src/app/app.component.ts (95,7): Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean[][]'.
```

I just need to get array as the following :

```
isCollapsedCyc[0] = true;
isCollapsedCyc[1] = false;
//
isCollapsedDet[0, 0] = true;
isCollapsedDet[0, 1] = true;
isCollapsedDet[1, 0] = false;
isCollapsedDet[1, 1] = true;
```

Comment: i can only do `isCollapsedDet[1][1] = true` just set `isCollapsedDet : boolean[]` and each item `isCollapsedDet[i] = []`

Comment: You might inspire yourself from answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875051/declare-an-array-in-typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add values to an array by nesting them with comma. 
Type `boolean[][]` means that there will be an array of arrays of booleans, so something like for example:

```
[[true, false], [false, true]] // this is boolean[][] or Array<Array<boolean>>
```

if you want to set the value for it, you need to nest it as an ordinary array:

```
isCollapsedDet[0, 0] = true; 
    // error - comma has nothing to do there
isCollapsedDet[0][0] = true; 
    // success - element isCollapsedDet[0][0] in array isCollapsedDet[0] is true
```

More about arrays in TypeScript can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) - and a bit more advanced types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Some useful answers found here: [Multidimensional array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144580/typescript-multidimensional-array-initialization)

Other links: [TypeScript Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

Comment: Thank you for you ALL, specially for the prompt answers. It's working now

Comment: because I use the isCollapsedDet in template,  is this correct ?  <span *ngIf="!isCollapsedDet[i][j]"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

Comment: yes. probably, if the `i` and `j` variables are type of integer and the value exist in array - it should work

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need the elements you mentioned, you could do:

```
let isCollapsedDet: boolean[][] = [[], []];
let isCollapsedCyc: boolean[] = [];

isCollapsedCyc[0] = true;
isCollapsedCyc[1] = false;

isCollapsedDet[0][0] = true;
isCollapsedDet[0][1] = true;
isCollapsedDet[1][0] = false;
isCollapsedDet[1][1] = true;
```

Or simply:

```
let isCollapsedDet: boolean[][] = [
    [true, true], [false, true]
];

let isCollapsedCyc: boolean[] = [true, false];
```

which can be reduced further because the compiler will infer the types based on the initialization:

```
let isCollapsedDet = [
    [true, true], [false, false]
];

let isCollapsedCyc = [true, false];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are accessing a property in any class and if you want to make it as a class member then don't forget to mention `this` and as Dawid said you can't assign values by separating indexes with `comma(,)`

```
export class HelloWorld implements OnInit{

  // Declaring the variable for binding with initial value
  yourName: string = '';
  public isCollapsedDet : boolean[][] = [[], []];
  isCollapsedCyc : boolean[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isCollapsedCyc[0] = true;
    this.isCollapsedCyc[1] = false;
    //
    this.isCollapsedDet[0][0] = true;
    this.isCollapsedDet[0][1] = true;
    this.isCollapsedDet[1][0] = false;
    this.isCollapsedDet[1][1] = true;
  }
}
```