# How to assign a array in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

```
 get_bid() {
    let higest_bid_array:any[];
    for(let i=0; i < this.crypto.length;i++) { 
      higest_bid_array =  this.crypto[i].highestBid;
    }
    return higest_bid_array;
  }
```

I've declared the variable as an array.

```
higest_bid_array:any[];
```

Here `crypto` is an array with values for example: `crypto[i].highestBid` 
 has the value **[1234, 5647, 8500]**;

How do i assign the values of `crypto` to `higest_bid_array`;

> **higest_bid_array** should return `[1234, 5647, 8500]`, it now returns only **8500** i,e. the last value of that array.

where am i going wrong ? thanks.

Comment: Can you post your expected data structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - multidimensional array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144580/typescript-multidimensional-array-initialization)

Comment: use `higest_bid_array: number[][]`, check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

Comment: higest_bid_array.push(this.crypto[i].highestBid) in for loop ?

Comment: Can you please say, what exactly is going wrong? Is an error thrown? Is the assigned data wrong?

Comment: It outputs only the last value of that array, referring  to the example above, it returns the last value **8500**

Comment: @mxr7350 thanks mate, i never noticed your comment. Your answer was right. :)  Thanks guys it much helped. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the array every time within your loop. You probably want to `push` values to the array within the for-loop.

```
get_bid() {
    let higest_bid_array:any[];
    for(let i=0; i < this.crypto.length;i++) { 
      higest_bid_array.push(this.crypto[i].highestBid);
    }
    return higest_bid_array;
  }
```

Read on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) if you want to know more about the Array push method.